# Complex Apache redirect

Tags: php, apache, magento, redirect

I have a magento installation with 2 websites
mydomain.net and mydomain.com
Both stores have different category structure but the page products are the same and I can see all products page using the root without using the category structure.

Example of this:
www.mydomain.net/product1.html is the same than
www.mydomain.net/category/product1.html

But in mydomain.com the category tree might be different.
Example:
www.mydomain.com/product1.html is the same than
www.mydomain.com/category/subcategory/product1.html

I need to create a redirect from all my pages in the .net to the .com, but pointing to the shortest URL, meaning after the first /.

Examples of how it should work:

**www.mydomain.net to www.mydomain.com

www.mydomain.net/product1.html to www.mydomain.com/product1.html

www.mydomain.net/category/product2.html to www.mydomain.com/product2.html

www.mydomain.net/category/subcategory/sub/sub/sub/product3.html just to www.mydomain.com/product3.html**

How can I do this for my magento installation? I suppose its with appache redirects in the index.php file ?

Could you please provide me with some kind of code or configuration to do this, because I dont have any experience with Apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not thinking it's possible to do using apache redirects. Instead, I recommend you to use Magento Catalog URL rewrites (Admin panel / Catalog / Manage URL rewrites)

Comment: I tried editing one product but the target path is a disabled field.

Comment: It's OK that the target path is disabled. Magento Catalog URL Rewrites guide: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/seo/how_to_work_with_magento_url_rewrite_rules

Comment: what about if I just want to redirect everything from mydomain.net to mydomain.com homepage with a simple apache redirect, is it possible? how could I do that?

Comment: Leave only `Redirect 301 / http://mydomain.com` in the `.htacess` file on the mydomain.net server.